# Python update geojson properties

Tags: python, geojson

I have a geojson feature collection dataset with a lot of features. I want to add/update the properties of each feature with properties of a json file. The unique identifier of both datasets is the "uuid" value.

This is the geojson format:

```
mtx = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            }
        },
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": 1,
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        5.36516933279853,
                        51.5510854507331
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "OBJECTID": 1,
                    "PK_UID": 1,
                    "uuid": "1efa8916-c854-465b-80f5-1f02fd25fb31",
                    "road": "A2",
                    "lane": 1,
                    "km": 134.96,
                    "bearing": 148.02261,
                    "locid": "A2134.96"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": 2,
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        5.05380200345974,
                        52.3264095459638
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "OBJECTID": 2,
                    "PK_UID": 2,
                    "uuid": "73bf3758-6754-433f-9896-d03c0673ae55",
                    "road": "A1",
                    "lane": 3,
                    "km": 11.593,
                    "bearing": 113.404253,
                    "locid": "A111.593"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this is the json format:

```
msi= [
        {
            "uuid": "1efa8916-c854-465b-80f5-1f02fd25fb31",
            "road": "A2",
            "carriageway": "R",
            "lane": "1",
            "km": "134.960",
            "display": "blank",
            "display_attrs": "{'flashing': 'false'}",
            "speedlimit": "null"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "73bf3758-6754-433f-9896-d03c0673ae55",
            "road": "A1",
            "carriageway": "R",
            "lane": "3",
            "km": "11.593",
            "display": "blank",
            "display_attrs": "{'flashing': 'false'}",
            "speedlimit": "null"
        }
    ]
```

So how can I make a python script that loop through the geojson features and update each feature properties with the matching properties from the json based on the "uuid" value?

I tried something like this but this didn't give me the expected result:

```
#Loop over GeoJSON features and update the new properties from msi json
for feat in mtx['features']:
    for i in range(len(msi)):
        if mtx['features'][i]['properties']['uuid'] == msi[i]['uuid']:
            feat ['properties'].update(msi[i])
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is supposed to be about answers to specific questions, and your question is not very specific. Which bit are you having problems with? Reading JSON files? Finding matching values from the other file? Updating dictionaries? Something else?

Comment: I've add additional information to my question to be more specific.

Comment: Hint: Given that `i` iterates over then length of `msi`, does `mtx['features'][i]` make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this (completely untested, so beware of mistakes...):

```
# Turn msi into a dictionary for easy access
msi_dict = {m['uuid']: m for m in msi}

for f in mtx['features']:
    f['properties'].update(msi_dict.get(f['properties']['uuid'], {}))
```

Comment: Isn't this correct? `f['properties']['uuid']`

Comment: @r-beginners You're right. Edited. Thanks!